# Expression expected error when trying to access element in an array java

Tags: java, android, arraylist, static, compiler-errors

I have created a class with static methods and I'm trying to access an element in the AllLanguages array

```
public final class AllLanguages {

    private static Language[] mLanguages;

    private  AllLanguages(Language[] languages) {
        mLanguages =  new Language[]
                {
                      new Language(R.drawable.united_kingdom, "English", "en"),
                        new Language(R.drawable.france, "French", "fr"),
                        new Language(R.drawable.israel, "Hebrew", "he"),
                        new Language(R.drawable.germany, "German", "de")
                };
    }

    public static Language[] getLanguages() {
        return mLanguages;
    }

    public static void setLanguages(Language[] mLanguages) {
        AllLanguages.mLanguages = mLanguages;
    }

    public Language getLanguage(int position) {
        return AllLanguages[position];
    }
}
```

At the last method (getLanguage) I run into the following compiler error "Expression Expected". Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

`AllLanguages` is a class not an array, so `AllLanguages[position]` is invalid syntax.

You need to change

```
public Language getLanguage(int position) {
    return AllLanguages[position];
}
```

to

```
public Language getLanguage(int position) {
    return mLanguages[position];
}
```